# Replace TextBox in MS-Word

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, textbox

I tried these two ways. One worked fine abut the other one didn't. Anyone explains why?

1- This one worked

```
Dim scount As Integer
Dim x As Integer
scount = WordDoc.Shapes.Count
For x = 1 To scount
WordDoc.Shapes(x).Select
If WordDoc.Shapes(x).TextFrame.HasText = True Then
With WordDoc.Shapes(x).TextFrame.TextRange.Find
  .Text = "World"
  .Replacement.Text = "505"
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue
  .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End If
Next x
```

2- This one didn't work

```
Dim Shp As Shape

For Each Shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
  Shp.Select
     With Selection.Find
        .Text = "World"
        .Replacement.Text = "Here"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second macro doesn't work because it doesn't address the TextFrame or TextRange issues. This would work:

```
Dim Shp As Shape
For Each Shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
  With Shp
    If .TextFrame.HasText = True Then
      With .TextFrame.TextRange.Find
        .Text = "World"
        .Replacement.Text = "Here"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
    End If
  End With
Next
```